# Enable xml declaration for SAML2 Requests with Sustainsys.Saml2

Tags: xml-declaration, sustainsys-saml2

I'd like to enable xml declarations for requests gernerated with `Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc` but so far didn't find a way to configure it.

I know declarations in XML1.0 are optional, but the IdP *(that I have no control over)* requires a declaration and sadly fixing/changing that is not an option.

Is there a way to enable xml declarations for `Sustainsys.Saml2` besides forking and changing the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question got me to look up what the SAML spec says about declarations: nothing. But in most examples I've seen of SAML2 messages, there is no declaration. So I'd say it should be a compatibility setting that can be enabled in special cases.

<del>There is no support for it right now, but it can be added (a well-written PR will be accepted).</del>

There is now support for notifications, that can be used to add XML declarations.

Comment: Hello @anders-abel, I have the same problem. Any modification since then? It would be very helpful :).

Comment: There is a PR that would allow this, but it has issues https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/pull/1158 and is not yet merged.

Comment: Thank you @anders-abel. I need that to be done by the end of the week. Do you know if this is something possible or if there is any workaround that I can use, before the PR is available?

Comment: @StéphaneLiwerant Mail me at anders@sustainsys.com to discuss options to get it done.